# Can I create relation in powerbi using column type as calender

Tags: powerbi

Can I create a relation among two tables using the column type that is of the type of calender, I tried doing this but I wasnt able to achieve! has anyone tried this?

Also How can I create a index column in two tables using direct query?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question -> Also How can I create a index column in two tables using direct query?  You can design a view , save and create a Indexed Views.  for more info see : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864(v=sql.105).aspx
you can join date columns if one is unique field.

Comment: I cant join the date columns whenever try this it gives me error

Comment: Is this solution suitable for PowerBi??